# Hiding Sign In With Google's "Welcome back, {name}"

Tags: javascript, api, google-plus

How do I make it so the Welcome back message doesn't appear everytime the user navigates to a new page?

[The message in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vewKa.png)

EDIT: Added code but its all the basic stuff to get a user signed in.

The callback:

```
function signInCallback(authResult) {
  gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
    if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
    // Update the app to reflect a signed in user
    // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
      $('#gConnect').hide();
      $('#authOps').show('slow');
       setProfileInfo(firstName);
       isUserInDatabase();
    console.log(authResult);

  } else {
    // Update the app to reflect a signed out user
    // Possible error values:
    //   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
    //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
    //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
    console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
  }
});
}
```

The sign-in button:

```
<div id="gConnect">
    <button class="g-signin"
        data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"
        data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
        data-clientId="819876183778-b7cuojcnn2fsi1rcm9k8sshnsebic68e.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        data-callback="signInCallback"
        data-theme="dark"
        data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin">
    </button>
  </div>
```

Loading the Google+ API:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
  </script>
```

Comment: Yeah....we're going to need a little bit more information about this...how about some code?

Answer (score 0):

So I'd recommend keeping track of the user's signed in state ([local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) or server side flags) and only showing the message if the state changes from not signed in to signed in.

Comment: I thought about that too...but I don't know what causes the popup. It must be something in the G+ API because I didn't write anything to do it.

Comment: What about this: `$('#authOps').show('slow');`? (I've never used G+ api myself, so I could be dead wrong

Comment: No, that div is just a container for all the info thats retrieved on sign in. I appreciate you trying to help a noob out though!